# Can't find or use OpenShift system groups

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin, okd

I'm trying to configure some rolebindings in OpenShift that I'm lead to believe would require the use of some OpenShift system groups. However when I try adding a role to any of the system groups, they can't be found.

One specific example that I'm trying to configure is a rolebinding that allows an image to be pulled from my 'demos' project into another project (including newly created ones).
My research into this has lead me to this particular page in the documentation, which describes a 'system:serviceaccount' group that sounds suited to my needs.
https://docs.okd.io/3.11/dev_guide/service_accounts.html#dev-sa-user-names-and-groups

Based on some of the examples provided on this page, I'm currently trying to use the following command to grant these permissions.

```
oc policy add-role-to-group system:image-puller system:serviceaccount -n demos
```

I expected this would allow me to pull in one of the images that I've got stored in the 'demos' project and deploy it into another project. However the command returns the following.

```
Warning: Group 'system:serviceaccount' not found
role "system:image-puller" added: "system:serviceaccount"
```

The role is still seemingly added to the group for the 'demos' project, however it's still not possible for me to pull one of the images stored in there into another project.

Comment: Seems like it's more of "fake" group, since it's a system group. "Real" groups should be visible with `oc get groups`. Also, I believe the group is `system:serviceaccounts`. I think you should be able to safely ignore the warning. Worst case scenario, just test to confirm.

Comment: @WillGordon Ah that's slightly embarrassing.. it does look like `system:serviceaccounts` grants me the permissions I want. I had originally added this role too when testing, but as it gives warnings both when adding the role and before deploying from an image in the project, assumed it didn't work. I've just tried deploying despite these warnings now and it works successfully. It's a shame the documentation uses the wrong name however! Thanks for your help.